# Create a new instance of my application when first instance is overloaded?

Tags: apache, tomcat, jenkins, devops

My application gets `x` hits per day and I know that if `y` hits come, my application will crash.

Is there a way that I can create another instance of my application when it reaches a certain LIMIT?  also I can't upgrade my server.

Answer (score 1):

If your application on AWS then you can use the Load balancer and Autoscaling group to scale your application servers based Request Count.
below link will be helpful to understand.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-scale-based-on-demand.html

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/07/introducing-target-tracking-scaling-policies-for-auto-scaling/

Comment: Unfortunately its all open source. Good articles gave me an idea on what i need to search .any links to acutal implementation of Load balancing or Autoscaling will be helpful

Comment: Maybe this will help : https://www.ctl.io/blog/post/aws-auto-scaling-load-balancing/